# Characteristic polynomial of a matrix in block form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A_1, ...,A_n$ be square matrices over a field $F$, and let $A$ have the block form
$$ A= \begin{bmatrix}  A_1 &  \\ & A_2 & & \\ & &...
                     & \\
& & & A_n      \end{bmatrix} $$ 
where all other off-diagonal entries are zero. Show that  characteristic polynomial $\Delta_A $ of A  is   $\Delta_A = \Delta_{A_1} \Delta_{A_2} ... \Delta_{A_n} $

Firstly, I observed that $ \Delta_A(A) = 0   \quad  \Leftrightarrow \Delta_A(A_1)=...=\Delta_A(A_n) =0 $. But I did not proceed from here.

Comment: In my case it is not the determinant being zero, it is the characteristic polynomial of A  taking arguments as A is zero, (By cayley hamilton theorem ). In the matrix you gave, $ \Delta_A = x(x-1)$ and $A_2 =1 $ also is a root of $\Delta_A$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is a determinant.
$$\lambda I - A =
 \begin{bmatrix}  \lambda I_1 - A_1 &  \\ & \lambda I_2 -A_2 & & \\ & &... & \\
   & & & \lambda I_n -A_n      \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $I_j$ are identity matrices of the same size as $A_j$. The determinant of a block-diagonal matrix is the product of the blocks' determinants:
$$ k_A(\lambda) = \det (\lambda I - A) = \det(\lambda I_1 - A_1) \det(\lambda I_2 - A_2) \cdot \ldots \cdot \det(\lambda I_n - A_n). $$